# How to pass HTML as json object in expressjs res.render function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I have a javascript function which returns HTML element and I want to pass that element further for user to view as HTML but it appears as a string for example "<" appears as (&lt) AND ">" appears as (&gt) etc

here is my code snippet:

```
res.render('index', { svg: '<div class="preview">MyCustomImage</div>' });
```

Appearing as:

```
&lt;div class=&quot;preview&quot;&gt;MyCustomImage&lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: How you get your template engine to output raw HTML instead of HTML escaped text depends on which template engine you are using.

Comment: @Quentin its pugjs template engine. and I know that if I interpolate this variable to javasript then I can append this as html to another element but when I replace back escaped characters &amp; become recursive and repeats itself many times.

Answer (score -1):

Set it as innerHTML to a node and assign the node value to a DOM element. This is what I mean

```js
const e = document.createElement('div');
const k = document.getElementById('one')
e.innerHTML = "&lt;div class=&quot;preview&quot;&gt;MyCustomImage&lt;/div&gt;";
k.innerHTML = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
```

Comment: That's an interesting hack, but an unsafe one. The content might include new lines (which would make the JS throw an exception).

Comment: @Quentin Can you give a sample content of what you mean and exactly how it'll throw exceptions.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/minokafeme/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Having server-side code generate client-side JS to generate HTML is needlessly complex when you could just have the  server-side code generate the HTML directly.